# Deleting a Node in Binary Search Tree Python

Tags: python-2.7, tree, binary-search-tree

Here is the code for deleting a node that has two children

```
parent_for_delete = node_for_delete
        replacer = node_for_delete.right
        while replacer.left:
            parent_for_delete = replacer
            replacer = replacer.left
        node_for_delete.data = replacer.data
        if parent_for_delete.left == replacer:
            parent_for_delete.left = replacer.right
        else:
            parent_for_delete.right = replacer.right
```

And here is the calling

```
if node_to_delete is not None:
        root.delete(deleted_node)
```

And I print the tree by drawtree library

The problem is for example when I have the tree below:

```
   5
 /   \
2     8
```

And I delete the 5 my tree takes shape as below :

```
2
 \
  8
```

My Expected result is:

```
8
 \
  2
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: What's wrong with that? What is your expected result?

Comment: expect result added